# Formatting NodeJS require for custom modules

Tags: node.js, module, require

So, this may already be answered but I've tried some of the suggestions I've already come across to no avail. I'm setting up my NodeJS project and since I have a development and production environment, I decided to create some config files to handle the different environments. However, whenever I visit the site and check the server logs I see this:

`module.js:549
    throw err;
    Error: Cannot find module '../config/config.index'`

Another thing to note... when I open up the command line and type in Node to bring up the interpeter, I can use require('../config/config.index'); and it works perfectly fine, but for some reason the script is having an issue with it. My project layout is like so...

```
- config
---- config.beta.js
---- config.global.js
---- config.index.js
---- config.live.js
---- config.test.js
- node_modules
---- alot of stuffs
- package-lock.json
- package.json
- server.js
```

I will also post my require statements in each file...

**server.js**

```
cfg = require("../config/config.index");
```

**config.index.js**

```
var appPool = process.env.APP_POOL_ID;

if (appPool == "LIVE") {
    env = "live";
} else if (appPool = "BETA") {
    env = "beta";
} else {
    env = "test";
}

var cfg = require('./config.'+env);
```

**config.beta.js**

```
var config = require('./config.global');
```

**config.test.js**

```
var config = require('./config.global');
```

**config.live.js**

```
var config = require('./config.global');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use module is some other file.

For that you need to add that module to export object. like

```
 exports.module.cfg  = cfg
```

And now if you use

```
require('./config/config.index')
```

in your server file. This should work

Comment: Where would the exports.module.cfg = cfg; line go?

Comment: in every module that you want to require in other files